# save and load using UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have made a class that I called `settings.h` and .m, where I have a textfield implementet.

```
@interface Settings : UViewController
{
  IBOutlet UITextField* ipAdress;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* ipAdress;
```

In my Settings.m i have nothing inside.

in my RootViewController im calling my settings using the pushViewController, because my Settings has a new view. in my Settings i have a back button. what i want is when i press the back buton i want my ipAddress that i have written to be saved and loaded.

My other class is my datamodel. in my datamodel i have my url and stuff like that, but when I run my simulator i have a view that hav a refesh button so it can refresh my xml fil, and a settings button when I press that button it continues to the next page, which is my setting page.

anyone who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the variable ipAdress from other classes, you have to synthesize it in your .m file
in Settings.m:

```
#import "Settings.h"
@implementation Settings
@synthesize ipAdress
@end
```

You are talking about saving the variable. Do you mean save it in a local database? If so you need to use SQLite.

Comment: No i'm calling a xml file, and i want to write the ip address in my textfield and when i press the back button it should save and load the ip address.

Comment: If you have loaded the ipadress gotten from XML into a string:
ipAdress.text =  IPAdressloadedFromXML;

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to retain this for use in your program. I would store the text into NSUserDefaults and retrieve it from there.

```
// save value this way
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
[defaults setObject:myField.text forKey:@"ipaddress"];
[defaults synchronize];

// retrieve value this way (Don't forget to declare *defaults like above)
NSString *myString = [defaults objectForKey:@"ipaddress"];
```